# Get rid of "et al" in inline citations with apacite

Tags: bibtex, natbib, apacite

Is there a way to get rid of the "et al" in my inline citations with apacite?  For inline citations I only want the first author to be displayed.

I've read through the docs, I've tried apacite and natbibapa, I've tried all the commands, i.e. `\citeauthor`, `\shortcite`, `\shortcitea`, `\shortciteauthor`, `\shortcites{key}\citet{key}`, `\citetkey`, etc.

I'm referencing 30+ papers so far, they all have 4+ authors at least, so my document is littered with the `et al`s.  e.g.

> Name et al (2010) ... and OtherName et al (2008) said, .. and some statement (AnotherName et al, 2001)

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.